# Affine Algebraic Curve cannot embed to Affine $n$-space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Is it possible to construct an affine curve that can not be a closed subvariety in $\mathbb{A}^n$ for given $n$? I know if this is projective space, $n$ is bounded, but how about affine space? Also, do the statement still hold for the irreducible affine curve?

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on what you take your definition of a curve to be and also what fields you work over.

If you assume that a curve is smooth and you're working over an infinite field, then every curve can be embedded in $\Bbb A^3$ for the same reasons every smooth projective curve can be embedded in $\Bbb P^3$: embed $X$ in some big $\Bbb A^n$, then project down, and as long as you project from a point not on the secant variety of $X$, you get an isomorphic curve. Since the secant variety is at most $2\dim X+1=3$ dimensional, you can always find a suitable projection.

If you allow singular curves, this result no longer holds. For instance, take an arbitrary curve and add some nilpotent elements at a closed point: we can make the tangent space to that point be of arbitrarily large dimension, and since closed immersions give injective maps on tangent spaces, the curve cannot embed in to any $\Bbb A^n$ with $n$ less than the dimension of the tangent space. Alternatively, we can take a smooth curve and glue together several points with distinct tangent directions to repeat the same sort of example.

If you're working over a finite field, you may also run in to cardinality issues. If $|X(\Bbb F_q)|>|\Bbb A^n(\Bbb F_q)|$, then $X$ cannot embed in $\Bbb A^n$ and indeed there are families of curves where the number of $\Bbb F_q$-rational points grows without bound (search "optimal tower" for concrete examples).

Comment: >>we can take a smooth curve and glue together several points with distinct tangent directions
In this case, is such a curve irreducible?

Comment: Yes, being the surjective image of an irreducible curve. The first example is the [nodal cubic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4331948/pushout-results-in-a-nodal-curve/4332178#4332178) $V(y^2=x^3+x^2)$, which is an $\Bbb A^1$ with two points glued together.

Comment: I see, but how do we prove in the general case?

Comment: The general case of what?

Comment: How do we prove that for $n$, there exist an irreducible curve that map subjectively to the smooth curve and glue together on one point with distinct tangent directions?

Comment: If you want the full-bore generality, see [here on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64294/gluing-along-closed-subschemes) for how to glue along closed subschemes. If you're content with a single example, consider the curve in $\Bbb A^n$ parametrized by $(p(t),tp(t),\cdots,t^{n-1}p(t))$ where $p(t)$ is a polynomial with $n$ distinct roots. Each root goes to $0\in\Bbb A^n$ and has distinct tangent directions. (Your comment mentions something about smoothness, do note that this curve is *not* smooth after gluing points together.)

Comment: Thank, sorry to the confusion, I just want to confirm that curve is irreducible...

Comment: The surjective continuous image of any irreducible topological space is irreducible (consider what would happen if you had a decomposition in to two nontrivial closed subsets). That means the curve we're talking about is irreducible.